# Compactifiable morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let's say a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is **compactifiable** if it admits a factorization $f = pj$ with $j:X\to P$ an open immersion and $p:P\to Y$ proper.

In SGA 4 Exp. XVII, Deligne says that Nagata proved that any morphism of separated integral northerian schemes is compactifiable but that he didn't understand the proof.

My questions:

- Where can I find a proof of Nagata's theorem?
- What about the complex analytic setting?

Comment: I just noticed that your question was "Where can I find a proof that any algebraic morphism of quasi-projective varieties is compactifiable?". This is pretty much obvious; just embed $X$ into $\mathbb P^N$, and take the closure of $X$ in $\mathbb P^N \times Y$.

Comment: Obvious indeed. Changed the question. 

Comment: Nagata's theorem doesn't need the "integral" hypothesis (even though Nagata's original formulation may have had it, possibly due to his use of earlier style of alg. geometry; I don't remember). The references mentioned below avoid it. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brian Conrad has written up a proof of Nagata's theorem, starting from notes of Deligne: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/nagatafinal.pdf. About the analytic case, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

For the algebraic case, see also Lutkebohmert: On compactifications of schemes.

Answer (score 1):

The following article of Conrad, Lieblich and Olsson settles the case of algebraic spaces.

http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0910/0910.5008v1.pdf

Comment: Rydh has a proof by a different approach (see his webpage, or C-L-O Introduction), and there is yet a 3rd approach in progress by Temkin & Temkin. 