# Compactification theorem for differentiable manifolds ?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, compactifications, gt.geometric-topology

Just parallelling [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22437/a-variety-always-have-a-compactification-is-there-an-easy-proof) question, that seemed not to admit an easy answer at all, let's "soft down" the category and ask the same thing in the case of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$-differentiable manifolds [Edit: we consider only manifolds without boundary].

Well, so:

> Is every differentiable manifold diffeomorphic to an open submanifold of a compact one?

**Edit:** As some comments have pointed out, there are manifolds for which the compactification theorem fails, so someone has suggested to change the question to the more meaningful:

> Which differentiable manifolds are diffeomorphic to an open submanifold of a compact one?

Comment: very nice question. perhaps better: which manifolds embed into a compact one?

Comment: The Whitney embedding theorem implies that any compact smooth manifold can be embedded in to a compact manifold with a high enough dimension. So the only interesting case is non-compact manifolds.

Comment: @Kelly: I don't understand your comment. I was asking for an *open* embedding into a compact one. I presume it's easy to embed any manifold as a locally closed submanifold of a sphere: just Whitney-embed as a closed submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^N$, send $\mathbb{R}^N$ diffeomerphically onto a ball, which sits inside a larger ball, and one-point-compactify the larger ball.

Comment: @unknown I was referring to Martin's comment "very nice question. perhaps better: which manifolds embed into a compact one." which to me seems not very interesting for compact manifolds. Martin did not specify an open embedding just an embedding.

Comment: @Kelly: Ok, I think maybe M. left the word "open" as understood, just referring to the context of the question.

Answer (score 36):

No.  A surface of infinite genus is not a submanifold of a compact surface.

Comment: ...That's true!...

Comment: @Richard, perhaps your answer refers to the question that was later deleted, but surely a compact surface may contain an open subset (i.e. codimension zero submanifold)  diffeomorphic to a surface of infinite genus. For example, the complement of a Cantor set in $S^2$ is such.

Comment: The complement of the Cantor set in $S^2$ is still genus 0, although it has countably many ends.

Comment: To see that Richard's answer is correct, note that the genus is the rank of the intersection form on $H_1$, which cannot drop in any embedding.  This generalizes to even-dimensional manifolds, e.g., an infinite connect sum of $\mathbb{CP}^2$'s.  Are there any odd-dimensional examples?

Comment: Thanks, Dylan. I clearly have not thought enough of topologically infinite surfaces.

Comment: I think the same intersection theory argument applies to the product of an infinite genus surface $S$ with a torus $T^k$ (of any dimension). If the surface handles are represented as $a_i, b_i$, then the intersection number of $a_i$ and $b_j\times T^k$ is $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ else. It follows that no two of $a_i$'s are homologous in the image of $S\times T^k$ under any codimension zero embedding.

Comment: Why can't one look at the rank of $H_i(M)$ divided by the annihilator of the pairing with $H_{n-i}(M)$ in the odd-dimensional case? That would seem to make the connected sum of an infinite number of $n$-dimensional tori an example in any dimension.

Comment: @Igor: "Richard, perhaps your answer refers to the question that was later deleted". Hm...No question has been delated so far.

Comment: @unknown, ignore that comment; I was confused. On the positive side the above comments give counterexamples to your first question in all dimensions > 1. I suggest you edit your question and write these examples up.

Answer (score 25):

There are contractible 3-manifolds which cannot be embedded in any compact 3-manifold. [Kister and McMillan](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=144322) constructed a variant of the Whitehead manifold $M'$ which is contractible but which cannot embed into $S^3$. From the Geometrization theorem, the universal cover of any compact 3-manifold embeds into $S^3$.  So if $M'$ embedded into a compact 3-manifold $M'\subset M$, its lift $M'\subset \widetilde{M}\subset S^3$ to the universal cover would give a contradiction.

Answer (score 16):

As everyone has said, the answer is "no".  You have to make assumptions to ensure that the "ends" of your manifold are sufficiently simple.  It appears hard to find using the refs Paul posted, but the key result about this is Larry Siebenmann's thesis.  I don't think this was ever published, but it is available on Andrew Ranicki's webpage [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/surgery/thesis.pdf).  Another source (also on Ranicki's webpage) for this is some lecture notes of Kervaire, available [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kervbrsi.pdf).

By the way, one obvious necessary condition is for your manifold to have a finitely presentable fundamental group (this is one of the problems with Richard's example).  A classic example to show that this is still not enough (even in dimension 3) is the [Whitehead manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold).

EDIT : I should also point out one beautiful recent about this.  Marden's Tameness Conjecture (recently proved independently by Agol and Calegari-Gabai) says that if M is a hyperbolic 3-manifold with finitely generated fundamental group, then M is homeomorphic to the interior of a compact 3-manifold.  The Whitehead manifold mentioned above shows that the assumption that M is hyperbolic is necessary.

Comment: The Whitehead manifold embeds in the 3-sphere, though.  It's the complement of the Whitehead continuum. 

Comment: Good point!  I didn't read the question carefully enough and assumed that he was asking for the interior of a manifold with boundary.

Comment: Yes, the problem as stated seems tricky: how to show that a given manifold cannot be the complement of any closed set in any compact manifold?

 

Answer (score 11):

There is a long history on this problem, starting, in  dimensions>4 with 
Browder-Levine-Livesay:

http://www.jstor.org/stable/2373259?origin=crossref

http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=189046

Follow MR to get to results in dimensions 3,4, etc. You have to first eliminate 
issues like Richard mentions using finiteness obstructions.

Comment: You are answering the question "is every differentiable manifold diffeomorphic to the interior of a compact one?". 

Answer (score 6):

I think none of the above posts answer the question "is every differentiable manifold diffeomorphic to an open submanifold of a compact one?". Rather they answer "is every differentiable manifold diffeomorphic to the interior of a compact one?" The reason for the confusion could be the latter question is fundamental in geometric topology, while the former one has little significance. Anyway,

The connected sum $V$ of infinitely many copies of $CP^3$'s is not diffeomorphic to an open subset of a compact manifold.

*EDIT:  Hats off to Torsten Ekedahl who pointed out in comments that my argument below is incorrect (thus I don't know whether the above statement about $V$ is true). I decided not to delete it because it illuminates some subtleties of the original question.*

The point is that any diffeomorphism onto an open subset pulls back the tangent bundle, and in  particular, pulls back the first Pontryagin class $p_1$. Thus if $V$ is an open subset of a compact manifold $M$, then its first Pontryagin class $p_1(V)$ lies in the image of $H^4(M)\to H^4(V)$, which is a **finitely generated** subgroup of $H^4(V)$, which is the infinite product of $\mathbb Z$'s corresponding to generators of $H^4(CP^3)$. The first Pontryagin class of $CP^3$ is a multiple of a generator of $H^4(CP^3)\cong\mathbb Z$, and removing a finite set of points from $CP^3$ does not affect the $4$th skeleton, so $p_1(V)$ does not lie in a finitely generated subgroup of $H^4(V)$.

I am curious to see low-dimensional answers to the question "is every differentiable manifold diffeomorphic to an open submanifold of a compact one?"

Comment: I don't understand, any element of an abelian group lies in a finitely
generated subgroup. Also $H^4(V)$ is the product not the sum of copies
of $\mathbb Z$. If one among the compact manifolds include
those with boundary it may not even be true that $H^4(M)$ is finitely
generated.

Comment: @Torsten, thanks for catching the typo. I edited to replace "sum" by "product". On the other hand, any compact manifold (with or without boundary) has finitely generated homology and cohomology. In the smooth case this is easy to see because by Morse theory they are homotopy equivalent to a finite cell complexes. Also this is a non-issue for if $V$ embeds to a manifold $M$ with boundary, $V$ also embeds into the double of $M$ along the boundary, which is closed.

Comment: You are right that there are no problem for f.g. of $H^4(M)$, my bad. However, I still do not understand your contradiction. $p_1(V)$ lies in the finitely generated subgroup $\mathbb Z p_1(V)$ so where is the contradiction?

Comment: By the way there is a beautiful argument in Spanier: Algebraic topology for the finite generation of homology for a compact manifold (with boundary which I should have remembered). Finite generation is algebraically derived from Poincaré duality and the universal coefficient formula.

Comment: Let me make an attempt. Pick a sequence of points on $V$ without limit point in $V$ and let $x$ be a limit point in $M$. A coordinate open neighbourhood of $x$ in $M$ must contain an (infinite number of) copies of $CP^3$ so that the tangent bundle of $CP^3$ minus the attaching points is trivial which is not possible as non-triviality is detected by $p_1$.

Comment: @Torsten, thanks so much for catching an error in my reasoning. In your argument with limit points it is unclear to me why a small open neighborhood of the limit point necessarily contains infinitely many $CP^3$'s. It does contain points from infinitely many $CP^3$'s, but each $CP^3$ could be spread out over several coordinate charts.

Comment: I am getting skeptical about my suggested argument as what I more or less say is that there are only two boundary points of $V$ in $M$ which is not clear.

Answer (score 6):

I'm just trying to give a partial solution to the second question.
Those examples had been mentioned in the previous posts. That is, finding manifolds which are open interiors of compact manifolds with boundary. This direction is natural since there are classical results regarding embedding compact manifold into Euclidean space of sufficient high dimension. So, for open manifolds, if they can be compactified such that the resulting spaces are compact manifolds with boundary, then classical results apply. However, examples provided here include manifolds with noncompact boundary, i.e., manifolds with uncountably many ends. Most of the results can be found in the joint paper with Guilbault https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.05995.
Here I just wanted to make a quick summary.
An $m$-manifold $M^m$ with (possibly empty) boundary is *completable* if there exists a compact manifold $\widehat{M^m}$ and a compactum $C \subseteq \partial \widehat{M^m}$ such that $\widehat{M^m}-C$ is homeomorphic to $M^m$. In this case $\widehat{M^m}$ is called a (manifold) *completion* of $M^m$. One can change the homeomorphism to diffeomorphism or PL homeo. for other categories.

Dim = 0,1 are obvious.

Dim = 2, we can't find a complete classification in the literature, so we provided a theorem in that paper. That is, a connected 2-manifold is completable iff it has finitely generated first homology. This is mainly based on classical work of Kerekjarto and Richards.

Dim = 3, it's mainly due to [Tucker](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938374900196), where he showed that a
3-manifold can be completed if and only if each component of each clean neighborhood
of infinity has finitely generated fundamental group.

Let me talk about dimensions $\geq 6$ first. Then I'll go back to dimensions 4 and 5. The first breakthrough regarding this problem was due to Siebenmann in 1965. In his PhD thesis, he proved that an open n-manifold $M^n$ is completable (it was called collarable by that time) iff
(1) M is inward tame, (2) the end is pro-$\pi_1$ stable and (3) the Wall finiteness obstruction of the end vanishes.
In 1983, [O'Brien](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864183900275) generalized the theorem to one-ended manifold with possibly non-empty boundary.

In our paper, we dropped the O'Brien's assumption on that manifolds are one-ended. By properly generalizing Siebenmann's conditions, we proved that manifolds of dimension at least 6 are completable iff they are inward tame, peripherally $\pi_1$-stable at infinity, of zero Wall and Whitehead torsion. Our proof is based on PL manifolds, but one can employ standard techniques such as "rounding off corners" to handle the other catergories.

Our theorem is still true in dimension = 5 provided that the fundamental groups are good in the sense of Freedman and Quinn.

The theorem fails in dimension = 4. [Kwasik-Schultz](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938388900237?via%3Dihub) and (independently) [Weinberger](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02779663) discovered that there are open 4-manifold satisfying Siebenmann's condition but fail to be collarable.

Just a quick comment on Ian's reference to a contractible open manifold $M'$ constructed by Kister-McMillan which doesn't embed in $S^3$. The example was first proposed by R. H. Bing. Haken further proved that $M'$ doesn't embed in any 3-manifold using his finiteness theorem. Recently, I showed that $M'$ can't be embedded in any compact, locally connected and locally 1-connected metric space. https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.02628

**Edit** As Ben McKay pointed out, my previous writing might cause confusion. So, some clarifications has been added.

Another direction to tackle OP's question is to embed manifolds into compact manifolds of same dimension. I think the 2-dimensional case of the second question is tractable via Ian Richards' [classification of noncompact surfaces](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-106-02/S0002-9947-1963-0143186-0/S0002-9947-1963-0143186-0.pdf). That is, we need to exclude surfaces of infinite genus and infinite degree of nonorientability.

For higher dimensions, although exotic contractible open manifolds like Whitehead manifold and Davis' manifolds do embed in spheres, a classification is harder even for contractible open manifolds in general like the one mentioned in Ian Agol's answer. For a futher discussion in this direction, see a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434759/classification-of-contractible-open-n-manifolds-which-embed-in-a-compact-n-manif) posted by myself.

Comment: The plane with the integers deleted lies as an open set in the plane, hence in the sphere, but has infinite first homology. So being completeable is stronger than being diffeomorphic to an open set in a compact manifold, which is really the question, it seems to me.

Comment: @BenMcKay Yes, you are right. The phrasing may cause ambiguity. I just wanted to provide a class of manifolds which are completable, therefore, embeddable as an open subset in a compact manifold. I was aware of the difficulty of giving a complete solution.