# Classification of contractible open n-manifolds which embed in a compact n-manifold

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

> Does there exist a classification of contractible open $n$-manifolds ($n\geq 3$) which embed in a compact $n$-manifold? More general, does there exist a classification of contractible open $n$-manifolds which embed in a compact, locally connected and locally 1-connected metric space of the same dimension?

The question is trivial in dimension $\leq 2$. For $\dim =3$, [Messer-Wright](https://msp.org/pjm/1979/82-1/p14.xhtml) provided a classification for open manifolds constructed using nested sequence of solid tori, which essentially based on Haken's finiteness theorem saying that there is an upper bound on the number of incompressible, nonparallel surfaces in a compact 3-manifold. Combining with a result obtained by [McMillan](https://www.ams.org/tran/1962-102-02/S0002-9947-1962-0137105-X/S0002-9947-1962-0137105-X.pdf) that every irreducible, contractible, open 3-manfold is a monotone union of handlebodies (only 0- and 1-handles), one can almost get a classification for the first part of the question. The second part of the question is harder. In my [paper](https://msp.org/agt/2021/21-3/p05.xhtml), it is shown that blowing up the upper bound on number of incompressible, nonparallel surfaces in a contractible open manifold will yield a manifold which does not embed in any compact, locally connected and locally 1-connected metric space of the same dimension. However, it is unknown if having such an upper bound (which is nearly Messer-Wright's necessary and sufficient condition for first part of the question) is necessary for a contactible open 3-manifold being embedded in a compact, locally connected and locally 1-connected metric 3-space.

For $\dim \geq 4$, the construction of exotic contractible open manifolds is more flexible. For instance, the famous Davis' manifolds. However, Ancel-Siebenmann showed that Davis manifolds $M$ admit a $\mathcal{Z}$-compactification, and the sewing of two copies of the $\mathcal{Z}$-compactified $M$ along the boundary is homeomorphic to $S^n$, therefore, Davis' manifolds must embed in a compact $n$-manifold. That means the remaining job of the classification should focus on manifolds which are more exotic. Of course, one may use a standard PL topology technique (i.e., "drill a tunnel" based on a regular neighborhood of a ray) to extend Messer-Wright's classification to higher dimensions in order to handle some exotic contractible open manifolds constructed in a similar flavor. But I guess it's just a tip of a giant iceberg.